# xhr method is case-sensitive?

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest

I find that I can use both get post put delete method in uppercase or lowercase,But I can only use patch method uppercase to make it work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PATCH',url); //works
xhr.open('patch',url); //get error net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
xhr.send();
```

[image]

Comment: That depends on your server.

Comment: But it cause error in browser,my server don't get the request

Comment: The method belongs in `xhr.open`, not `xhr.send`.

Comment: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE means that _your server_ sent an empty response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP request methods are defined to be uppercase. Section 3.1.1 of the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) says

> The request method is case-sensitive.

Since `XMLHttpRequest` simply sends the given request method to the server, the above proscription applies there as well.

Some servers may accept lowercase request methods as an application of the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), but for the same reason you should not send them.